# How does one make sense of singular solutions to constant mean curvature equation?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

**Background:**
Consider the following ODE:
$$\left(\frac{r^2 \dot{f}}{\sqrt{1+r^2(\dot{f})^2}}\right)' = c r$$
where $c$ is some positive constant (Lagrange multiplier), $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\pi]$ is the angular function associate with the set $A=\{(r,\theta):\theta\in(-f(r),f(r))\}.$

Then the above ode essentially says that the mean curvature of the boundary of the set $A$ is constant. Thus we should expect that $A$ is ball of some radius $r_0$ and therefore $f(r) = \pi \chi_{[0,r_0)}$.

However clearly $f$ is not smooth in this case so one cannot just check if $f$ satisfies the ode above. I am familiar with the notion of weak solutions and so in particular the weak derivative of $\dot{f} = \pi(\delta_{0}-\delta_{r_0})$ but I am not sure how to compute the quantity $\frac{r^2 \dot{f}}{\sqrt{1+(r\dot{f})^2}}$ in the distributional sense.

**Question:**
To summarize, is it possible to make sense of $f(r)=\pi\chi_{[0,r_0)}$ as a solution to the above ode?

**Note:** For reference here is the [paper](https://publications.hse.ru/pubs/share/folder/9engcj52e4/63400675.pdf). See Eqn (4) in Lemma 4.1 for the ODE given above.

Comment: are you certain this is the correct equation? if $r$ has dimension of length the dimensions of both sides of the equation do not agree; you may have a better response if you point to a source for your ODE.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, thanks for your comment. I added the paper!

Comment: if you look at the bottom of page two, the authors say that the surface of constant curvature is _either a ball_ or satisfies this ODE; so it seems they exclude the case of a ball; to make sense of this equation for a ball you would need to consider the square of a delta function, which in general does not make sense.